# How to find MySQL process list and to kill those processes?

Tags: mysql, kill-process

The MySQL database hangs, due to some queries.

How can I find the processes and kill them?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Here is the solution:

1. Login to DB;
2. Run a command `show full processlist;`to get the process id with status and query itself which causes the database hanging;
3. Select the process id and run a command `KILL <pid>;` to kill that process.

Sometimes it is not enough to kill each process manually. So, for that we've to go with some trick:

1. Login to MySQL;
2. Run a query `Select concat('KILL ',id,';') from information_schema.processlist where user='user';` to print all processes with `KILL` command;
3. Copy the query result, paste and remove a pipe `|` sign, copy and paste all again into the query console. **HIT ENTER. BooM it's done**.

Comment: That query is great! For anyone looking at this with light MySQL experience you can also filer the query by `Host`, `db`, `Command`, `Time`, `State`, or `Info`:


`SELECT concat('KILL ',id,';') from information_schema.processlist where Command='Sleep';`


or 


`SELECT concat('KILL ',id,';') from information_schema.processlist where Time>'300';`

Comment: Thanks for the query! I used an enhanced version that could save some manual editing time: `select group_concat(concat('KILL ',id,';') separator ' ')` so they all land on one line that can be copy-pasted

Comment: The query is ok, but you can end up killing your own process. I would review the list of process ids before rerunning the "kill all".

Comment: Tweaking @architectonic 's comment to get me something immediately easier to handle off the clipboard (even with the pesky opening and closing double quotes)   
```SELECT group_concat(concat('KILL ',id,';') SEPARATOR ' \n') AS KILL_EVERYTHING FROM information_schema.processlist;```

Answer (score 47):

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(stat SEPARATOR ' ') from (select concat('KILL ',id,';') as stat from information_schema.processlist) as stats;
```

Then copy and paste the result back into the terminal.
Something like:

```
KILL 2871; KILL 2879; KILL 2874; KILL 2872; KILL 2866;
```

Answer (score 23):

You can do something like this to check if any `mysql` process is running or not:

```
ps aux | grep mysqld
ps aux | grep mysql
```

Then if it is running you can `killall` by using(depending on what all processes are running currently):

```
killall -9 mysql
killall -9 mysqld
killall -9 mysqld_safe
```

Comment: The OP is asking about processes running within the MySQL server.

Comment: Although not what was asked for, it helped as this is the first item google returned when searching how to kill all mysqld processes on linux ;)

Comment: On a related note, one should always try with `kill -15` and resort to `kill -9` only if process continues to run. with `kill -15` you are giving process a chance for graceful termination.

Answer (score 2):

On RDS:

```
SELECT
  concat('CALL mysql.rds_kill(',id,');')
  FROM information_schema.processlist
  ORDER BY time;
```

Comment: `KILL [PID];` works just as fine on RDS.